# Does angular datatables(npm Package) support for ionic components too. For ion-row and ion-col

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datatables

Does "angular datatables"(npm Package) support for ionic components too? For ion-row and ion-col.

angular data tables is working with plain HTML `<table> <td><tr>` tags... But not with ionic.
I have attached the screenshot below.

[image: Added data tables to ionic grid. not working]

Here is the one with basic HTML tags, Which is working..

[image: With Basic HTML tags]

OUTPUT of these two:
[image: OUTPUT with 2 options]

Or

Is there any package for ionic components to add pagination?

Comment: it should work.

Comment: honestly, it looks like both are working fine. Why do you say that this isn't working? do you have an error in the console?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, But If you see, For ionic I do not have any pagination printed.

Answer (score 0):

**YES!**
You can use basically any angular package inside iconic. You can also use `datatables` witouth the `angular-datatables` wrapper.
But the goal of ionic is to look native, and those datatablese doesn't look very native.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not getting the expected result when I use the angularDatatables with the ionic project. If I use the same package with just the angular project it works fine...